# Why use Parse to turn a string into an int?

Tags: c#

I have made a little calculator:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int input1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    int input2 = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    int Result = input1 + input2;
    textBox3.Text = Result.ToString();
}
```

Why can't I just do  `textBox3.Text = Result;` when I already told them that the result is int type in the line before?

Comment: Your `textBox3.Text` is a string type. That's the reason you have to convert your `Result` to string

Comment: These are basic rules to learn ASAP. For example, try to type something that is not a number in one of your input textboxes.

Comment: it gives me an error cause the input is int and i cant give it string type i can do if to fix it but is all textbox.text are strings? even if the result is gonna be number?

Comment: @kariryzh Yes - all textboxes use `string`. There is a difference between `"1"` and `1` - the first being the ascii representation, and the second being the *actual value* of `1`.

Comment: See this for more information http://www.asciitable.com/ - If you're still stuck, I'd highly recommend reading some beginners books or going through tutorials

Comment: You should also look into using `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse`.  As @Steve mentioned, if you try and parse a string that's not a valid `int` value, it will give you an error.  However, by using `TryParse`, it won't throw an error and will instead return `true` or `false`.  You can then use that result in an `If` statement or similar to either calculate the `Result` or warn the user they didn't enter a valid number.

Comment: `TryParse` is a good idea, especially in this situation @Calcolat and also introduces parameter modifiers just in case the op isn't familiar. So then it's back over to SO to see what `out` and `ref` are all about! Learning is fun.

Answer (score 2):

When I need to explain *data types*, I often use the analogy with *shapes*.

A *data type* is a shape, that *forms* the behaviour of the variable of the specified type. When a variable of a given type is created it holds the *description of the type* and a *value*. Variables with the same *shape* can be connected together with the help of operators (for example `+`).

Two variables from a different type (*shape*) can not be connected directly together - they need a converter / wrapper.

A converter makes for example from the shape triangle a circle or a wrapper masks the triangle as a circle.

Back to your example. `TextBox` controls can hold only the data type `string`, meaning they are incompatible with the shape of an `int`. You already have converted the content of the `string` to an `int` using `int input1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);`.

That is why you can not simply assign the `Result` variable to the `Text` property - their shapes are different, so you need to convert the `int` back to `string` using the `ToString()` method. You could also write `textBox3.Text = (input1 + input2).ToString();`.

The shape analogy can be used to understand parameters passing - as long you know the *signature* of a method `int add(int a, int b)`, you know exactly what you need to put when you are calling a method (two `int`'s) and what kind of type to expect as a result (an `int`). For example `String result = add(1,2);` will not work because the signature is not as expected, `result` should be of type `int` in order to work (`int result = add(1,2);`) or the call to `add(1,2)` should be converted to `string` (`string result = add(1,2).ToString();`).

Same goes with classes and objects - a class is a custom data type, so a custom shape. As long two instances of a class (objects) have the same shape they can be connected or assigned to each other.

This is a very simplified explanation (but still it helped my trainee in the past) so take your time and have a look at the C# MSDN documentation for a thorough explanation of data types.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I just do  textBox3.Text = Result; when I already told them
>   that the result is int type in the line before?

Even though you 'told' that the result would be of type int, the compiler needs to know how to interpret/transform the string into an int.

int.Parse is one way of doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may want to start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs7y5x0x%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) with C# Data Types. As for your question. `TextBox.Text` is of type `string`. Check out MSDN articles for the different controls that you're using and their properties, such as this [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on `TextBox.Text`

Answer (score 0):

`textBox3.Text` is a type of string while `Result` is a type of `int` and in your code you are assigning `int` value to a `string` which is wrong. You need to transform ones type to the other.